# How display php echo results in different styles?

Tags: php, css, mysql

I have 2 php echo results from my mysql database. Their request is common and wrapped into one line :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN ('9','10')";
```

I want only the **first result** to be displayed in **h3 style**, and the second result to be displayed in **normal p style**.  Using the code below **the 2 results are displayed in h3 style.**

How do I fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

```
enter code here

<div class="one-third wow fadeIn">
<span class="circle"><span class="ico pig"></span></span>
<h3>

<?php
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
echo "connection error" ;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN ('9','10')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
{echo $data ['FR']."<br>"; }    } else {echo "---"; }?></h3>
<p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <?php
        $conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
                echo "connection error" ;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN ('9','10')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
            while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                  if($i == 0){
                        echo "<h3>".$data ['FR']."<br></h3>"; 
                    }else{
                        echo "<p>".$data ['FR']."<br></p>"; 
                    }
                     $i++;
            }    
    } else {
        echo "---"; 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, it's working, kranthi ! You're a chief ! Thank you. very much !